# Nginx timeouts don't seem to apply to a location

Tags: nginx

If I have the following timeout rules in my http block:

```
keepalive_timeout 1s;
send_timeout 1s;
```

And the following location:

```
location = /slow {
    echo_sleep 10;
    echo "So slow";
}
```

I would expect `/slow` to trigger a 408 or 504 (timeout), but it's actually honouring that request. Which says to me that I'm handling timeouts incorrectly. So how would I limit the length of time a request takes to be processed by nginx?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly says

> Sets a timeout for transmitting a response to the client. The timeout is set only between two successive write operations, not for the transmission of the whole response. If the client does not receive anything within this time, the connection is closed.

`echo_sleep 10;` and then `echo "xxx"`, so the response time will start from `echo` and not from `echo_sleep`

Comment: So you're saying I need to do echo first, then echo_sleep?

Comment: This is a config file and not a code file. So changing order won't change the behavior.

Comment: Ahh I get you. I think I'm using the wrong directive for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to automatically terminate a request, that takes longer than a given period of time. 

I'm beginning to understand that connection keep alive is something slightly different.

Comment: They would work when you proxy the request to a upstream, then you can use things like `proxy_timeout`, `proxy_connect_timeout`. See all available options https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout